# How to make a div linkable?

Tags: html, hyperlink, shopify

I have a block on my Shopify theme's home page that is basically an image box with text over it and when the text is clicked, it links to a url.

I want the box itself to be linkable in case I don't use any text. This is the code below that makes the text a link.  How can I make the entire box the link?

```
  `<div class="text-center col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="img1">
        <a href="{{ settings.home_blockhtml_link_1 }}">             
          {{ 'home_html_1.png' | asset_url | img_tag:    settings.home_blockhtml_tilte_1, "img-responsive" }}                               
          <div class="description">
            <p class="title">{{ settings.home_blockhtml_tilte_1 }}</p>
            <p class="text">{{ settings.home_blockhtml_des_1 }}</p>         
            <p class="button hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"><a class="btn btn-outline-small" href="{{ settings.home_blockhtml_link_1 }}" title="{{ settings.home_blockhtml_buttontxt_1 }}">{{ settings.home_blockhtml_buttontxt_1 }}</a></p>
          </div>    
        </a>        
    </div>  
</div>
```

`

Comment: what about putting the `a` tag outside the outer `div` tag?

Comment: do you mean like stuartmccoll's suggestion below?  It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the `div` inside your `<a>` tags, like so, giving the `a` tag their own class. This will need CSS styling like so:

```
.className {
    display:block;
{
```

Now, the `<a>` tag inside the `<div>` will cause you issues, so you'll need to change this to element, the example below changes it to a `<span>`.

```
<a href="{{ settings.home_blockhtml_link_1 }}" class="className">
<div class="text-center col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<div class="img1">


      {{ 'home_html_1.png' | asset_url | img_tag:    settings.home_blockhtml_tilte_1, "img-responsive" }}

      <div class="description">
        <p class="title">{{ settings.home_blockhtml_tilte_1 }}</p>
        <p class="text">{{ settings.home_blockhtml_des_1 }}</p>

        <p class="button hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"><span class="btn btn-outline-small" title="{{ settings.home_blockhtml_buttontxt_1 }}">{{ settings.home_blockhtml_buttontxt_1 }}</span></p>
      </div>

    </div>

</div>

</a>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/88fx4p3x/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The div still does not link

Comment: Updated my original answer - didn't see the nested `a` tag originally, this probably would've caused issues.

Comment: This works although I didn't understand the CSS part.  I know how to add the class but I don't see where it is used in the HTML.  It worked without the CSS. Am I missing somethings?

Comment: Whoops, had added it into the JSFiddle, but forgot to actually add it to the element in the answer. Feel free to mark as an accepted answer if this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the `<a>` tag in front and behind of the div tags. That will make the div a hyperlink